# Load data into SQL Server using Powershell without Credential Prompt

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am trying to load a CSV file into a remote SQL Server instance. This is the command I am running:

```
Write-SqlTableData -DatabaseName my_db_name -TableName my_table_name -ServerInstance my_server_instance -SchemaName dbo -InputData $data -force
```

I am trying to use the credential parameter, but it is giving me a prompt.  I want to automate this process, so I need to bypass the prompt.

```
Write-SqlTableData -DatabaseName my_db_name -TableName my_table_name -ServerInstance my_server_instance -SchemaName dbo -Credential $cred -InputData $data -force
```

Comment: You read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/write-sqltabledata?view=sqlserver-ps) specifically the *credential* parameter.

Comment: @DaleBurrell Updated my question based on your comment.

Comment: I think you need to practice your google-fu :) [Get Credential Without Prompt](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Office-365/cred-Get-Credential-without-asking-for-prompts-in-powershell/m-p/483274)